# Flutter intl missing flutter_gen files

Tags: flutter, integer, builder

Anyone had a problem with flutter intl package?

I keep getting the same import error, but the strings are actually working.

The flutter_gen are generated

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you add platform dependent package? try flutter clean?

Comment: What is a platform dependent package?

Did flutter clean, restarted app - its a big application already actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common Flutter problem... but the solution is easy. You just have to restart the Dart Analysis Server.

In IntelliJ is the red button in the "Dart Analysis" tab.

[image]

Comment: this worked. thx !!! The errors do reappear after flutter pub get

Comment: Yes, it's annoying. This problem has been mentioned several times on Flutter's GitHub... but the thread ends up being closed due to inactivity. I guess because it's not really a major bug.

Comment: Have you encountered this bug with any other packages or peculiar cases?

Comment: This is not a problem with specific packages, but with the tools that auto-generate code ('intl' is one of them). The problem happens when you do the 'flutter pub get', and then the Dart code analysis tool fails (not always, sometimes it works fine...). The simplest solution, right now, is to restart the tool.